# Javascript Object Placement / String Parsing Method

Tags: javascript, parsing

This JS function is intended to retrieve or place a value into an object with the nested keys as a string.

For example

```
var obj = {a: {b: [4]}};
parse_obj_key(obj, "a.b.0") should equal 4.
parse_obj_key(obj, "a.c", 2) should add another element to "a" named "c" with value 2.
```

The method works, but I'd like to clean it up if possible (or a more polished implementation which is publicly available).  I'd also love to know of any edge-case failures which can be found.

```
function parse_obj_key(obj, loc, val){
    var _o = obj;
    while (true){ 
        var pos = loc.indexOf('.');                        

        if (!_o || typeof _o != 'object'){
            $.log("Invalid obj path: " + loc + "\n" + JSON.stringify(obj));
            return null;      
        }                                                    

        if (pos === -1){
            if (val){
                _o[loc] = val;                 
                return obj;                                           
            } else {
                if (!isNaN(parseInt(loc)))
                    loc = parseInt(loc);

                return _o[loc];
            }
        }
        var part = loc.substring(0, pos);                    
        var loc = loc.substring(pos + 1);                     

        if (!isNaN(parseInt(part)))
            part = parseInt(part);   

        if (!(part in _o)){
            if (val)
                _o[part] = new object;                                        
            else
                return null;                                           
        }
        _o = _o[part];                      
    }                                                                         
}
```

Comment: I would suggest providing two different methods, one to get and one to set values (maybe both calling a common private method to retrieve the property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what's wrong with your code:

- Do not use variable names like `_o`. Get an editor with good auto-completion.
- `typeof _o != 'object'` does not do what you think it does: `typeof([1,2]) // "object"`.
  In general, doing those kinds of checks is a code smell.
- `if (!isNaN(parseInt(loc))) loc = parseInt(loc);`. Confusing and not needed.
  JavaScript: `['a', 'b']["1"] // 'b'`. Same goes for the other `isNaN`
- `in`. Do not do that check. `null` is a value, but what you want to return is the lack of value. It is `undefined` in JavaScript, and it is what will be returned if there is no value.
- Consider using `split` instead of `indexOf` and `substring`. It is much faster and makes the code more readable.

So, here is a neat version for you:

```
function chained(obj, chain, value){
    var assigning = (value !== undefined);
    // split chain on array and property accessors
    chain = chain.split(/[.\[\]]+/);       
    // remove trailing ']' from split   
    if (!chain[chain.length - 1]) chain.pop();
    // traverse 1 level less when assigning
    var n = chain.length - assigning; 
    for (var i = 0, data = obj; i < n; i++) {
        data = data[chain[i]];
        // if (data === undefined) return; // uncomment to handle bad chain keys      
    }

    if (assigning) {
        data[chain[n]] = value;
        return obj;
    } else {
        return data;       
    }
}
```

Blogged: http://glebm.blogspot.com/2011/01/javascript-chained-nested-assignment.html

Please come up with further improvements :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on how your solution is an improvement with regards to OP's code?

Comment: @Eric Done. Feel free to add more.

Comment: I mostly agree with your comments, except "Do not use strict comparison". I would rather suggest to use strict comparison all the time, trying to focus on "The Good Parts" (c) of JavaScript rather than its quirks. +1

Comment: I used _o to signify that it's a temporary var just to be mashed about in the loop, e.g. that it only meaningful for it's ref to the real obj.  I intended the typeof to work the way it did, I want to know if it's an array or an object (e.g. not a primitive), will it not work for this purpose?

Comment: I was not completely correct about your use of typeof. It will work for checking whether something is a primitive or not. However, if you try `parse_obj_key("awesome_string", "length")` it won't work because `"object"` is not the same as something that responds to methods. Cheers.

Comment: I agree with Eric. `==` and `!=` are evil. `0 == '' // true 0 == '0' // true '0' == '' // false!` or `' \t\r\n\f' == 0 // true` or even `',,,,,,' == Array(('i' <3, 'js', 'on a scale of 1 to 10, js is a ', 7))` although that exploits more than just `==`...

Comment: I, too, agree with Eric. How is `===` not embracing the language? You just have to _know_ that `domNode.property === 123` will always be false, so use ` === '123'`. Using `== 123` isn't embracing the language IMO, it's just relying on type coercion, which is slower and, in some times, making life harder: `dateInput == new Date()`... Besides, `aVar === +(aVar)` is _very_ common in JS

Comment: I removed the `==` bit, as you are all right :)

Answer (score 0):

I know little about javascript, and thought yours solution is fine.
glebm's code seems not working for `parse_obj_key(obj, "a.c.c.c", 2)`

I trying to modify your code to a recursion style, and it works, the "new object" goes wrong on my firefox, so I change it to = {}

```
function parse_obj_key(obj, loc, val) {
    if(!obj || typeof obj != 'object') {
        alert("error")
        return null
    }
    var pos = loc.indexOf('.');
    var part = loc.substring(0, pos);
    var endpart = loc.substring(pos+1);

    if (!isNaN(parseInt(part)))
        part = parseInt(part);

    if (pos === -1) {
        if (val) {
            obj[loc] = val
            return obj
        }
        else
            return obj[loc]
    }

    if (val) {
        if (!(part in obj)) 
            obj[part] = {}

        parse_obj_key(obj[part], endpart, val)
        return obj
    }
    else {
        return parse_obj_key(obj[part], endpart, val)
    }
}
```

Comment: I much prefer a recursive style like this to "while (true)" if you can get away with it. I would say, though, that you might want to consider refactoring the validation of `obj` into a separate method. `parse_obj_key` would validate the arguments, then call into the recursive helper function. That way the arguments are re-validated on every recursion. Not a big problem in this instance, but a pattern to consider for deeper recursion or move complex argument validation.

Answer (score 0):

My code is based off glebm's, but I've changed it so that array lookups must always use the `.` syntax. I made a few other tweaks such as creating an object chain if assigning to a nested key that doesn't yet exist.

```
function parse_obj_key(obj, key, value){
    var is_assigning = (value !== undefined);
    key = key.split('.');     

    var data = obj;
    var length = key.length - is_assigning;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var child = data[key[i]];
        var has_child = (child !== undefined);

        if (!has_child && !is_assigning) {
            $.log("Invalid obj path: " + key + "\n" + JSON.stringify(obj));
            return null;
        }

        if (!has_child) {
            child = {};
        data[key[i]] = child;
        }

        data = child;
    }

    if (is_assigning) {
        data[key[i]] = value;
    } else {
        return data;       
    }
}
```

If you're trying to create an optional parameter, you should check if it is undefined using `if (param !== undefined)`, rather than just `if (param)`, otherwise you'll have trouble setting falsy values such as `false`, `null`, `0` and `""`.

One of the things that allows this code to be much shorter is the observation that in javascript, `arr['a']['b'][0]` is the same as `arr['a']['b']['0']` - that is to say, array lookup using an integer is no different from array lookup using a string that contains a number. This avoids the need to parse the numbers like you do.

The other major saver is the use of split rather than indexing, which makes it easy to `for` loop over the parts of the key.

Comment: Your code fails to return `null` on `parse_obj_key({a: null}, 'a')`. Replacing `(!child)` with `child !== undefined` might fix it. Cheers

Comment: Cheers. I should listen to my own advice :P